# Jest with Babel ^7.0.0-beta.51 issue

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, yarnpkg, babel-jest

I followed everything you recommended me to make the Babel 7 work with the Jest.
I installed the `@babel/core` and `babel-core`. Still It does not work.

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "jest-cli": "^23.1.0"
  }
}
```

After `yarn jest`

```
yarn run v1.9.0-20180612.1255
$ /Users/m/Desktop/k/node_modules/.bin/jest
 FAIL  packages/services/src/Client/__tests__/Client.js
  - Test suite failed to run

    Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.

      at throwVersionError (node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:65:11)
      at Object.assertVersion (node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:13:11)
      at _default (node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs/lib/index.js:51:7)
      at node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Perhaps a useful [article for Babel 7 and Jest](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-testing-tutorial/) for anyone who is stumbling on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Saw your question on the Jest GitHub issues -- I think it was you, but I solved it on my end by going through the [`create-react-app` repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and seeing how they integrated Jest. Specifically, the [`packages/react-scripts/package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/package.json) file has what you need.

`"@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.46",
    "autoprefixer": "8.5.0",
+   "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",`

Add the line with the `+`, or change what version you have and you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the Jest page says it includes `babel-jest` I found that adding it to my project fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add --dev babel-jest babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0 regenerator-runtime
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/zh-Hans/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. Answers are best if they are complete in and of themselves. Can you add an explanation of what the OPs problem was how your answer solves the problem?